# Bokeh Plots Axis Value don't show completely

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I have just started exploring bokeh and here is a small issue I am stuck with. This is in regards with live graphs.

The problem is with the axis values. Initially if I start with say 10, till 90 it shows correct values but while printing 100, it only show 10 and the last zero(0) is hidden. It's not visible.

That is when it switches from 2 digit number to a 3 or more digit number only the first two digits are visible.

Is there any figure property I am missing or what I am not sure of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with current versions (around `0.12.10`) for now the best workaround is to increase `plot.min_border` (or `p.min_border_left`, etc) to be able to accommodate whatever the longest label you expect is. Or to rotate the labels to be parallel to the axis so that they always take up the same space, e.g. `p.yaxis.major_label_orientation = "vertical"`

Comment: Worked with major_label_orientation.